# calculate sum of factorials of digits of a 3 digit number

Tags: c++, factorial

I have written this c++ code to calculate the sum of factorial of digits in a three digit number but its not working:

output is:

Process returned -1073741571 (0xC00000FD)   execution time : 9.337 s
Press any key to continue.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
using namespace std;
unsigned fact(int n)
{
    if (n == 1|n==0)
        return 1;
    else
        return n * fact(n - 1);
}
int main()
{
    int num;
    int sum=0;
    int tmp;
    cout<<"Enter 3 digit number:\n";
    cin>>num;
    if(num<99|num>999)
    {
        cout<<"Not a 3 digit number!";
        return (1);
    }
    tmp = num%100;
    sum = sum+ fact(tmp);
    tmp = num%10;
    sum = sum+ fact(tmp);
    tmp = num%1;
    sum = sum+ fact(tmp);

cout<<"Sum of factorial of digits in a number:"<<sum;
return(0);
}
```

Comment: What will your `fact` function do with at 0?

Comment: edited to include 0;

Comment: I think you mean `||` not `|` (both times - although honestly they should work regardless, it's just a little odd). Anyway your bigger issue is the way you get the digits, `num%100` can be quite large...

Comment: What number are you entering, or does it not get to the point of taking input?

Comment: Also, `num<99` should be `num <= 99`. There are so many errors! You really should make more of an effort before posting your code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The digits of `num` are not `num % 100`, `num % 10,` and `num % 1`. Whatever gave you that idea?

Take for instance `num=567`. Then we have

`num % 100 = 67`

`num % 10 = 7`

`num % 1 = 0`

You need to think about it a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot how to select digits of a number this works now:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
using namespace std;
unsigned fact(int n)
{
    if (n == 1||n==0)
        return 1;
    else
        return n * fact(n - 1);
}
int main()
{
    int num;
    int sum=0;
    int tmp;
    cout<<"Enter 3 digit number:\n";
    cin>>num;
    if(num<=99|num>999)
    {
        cout<<"Not a 3 digit number!";
        return (1);
    }
    tmp = num%10;
    sum = sum+ fact(tmp);
    tmp = num/10%10;
    sum = sum+ fact(tmp);
    tmp = num/100%10;
    sum = sum+ fact(tmp);

cout<<"Sum of factorial of digits in a number:"<<sum;
return(0);
}
```